# Metrics on $\mathbb R^n$, Counting continuous functions and Open sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

Given the set $\mathbb{R}^n$ with metric $d$. We define continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ by open sets -we say that function is continuous iff the pre-image of every open set is open.

Let's say that number of open sets in $(\mathbb{R}^n,d)$ is $\mathfrak{c}$. Does that imply that the number of continuous function in $(\mathbb{R^n}, d)$ is $2^\mathfrak{c}$? Or maybe $\mathfrak{c}$? What if number of open sets is $2^\mathfrak{c}$?

Is it an open problem or known one?

Comment: To clarify, you are asking about continuous functions from $(\mathbb{R}^n, d)$ to $(\mathbb{R}^n, d)$?  That is, the preimage of a $d$-open set should be $d$-open?

Comment: Yes, preimage of d-open set should be d-open.

Comment: Any ideas? Is it too hard?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the general case, but I can start with the case where $d$ is the Euclidean metric or a topological equivalent. Here the answer is $\mathfrak{c}$. My proof uses the Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein theorem.

First there is an injection from $\mathbb{R^n}$, where you map a vector to a constant function. Second there is an injection to $(\mathbb{R}^n)^{\mathbb{Q^n}}$ given by the restriction map. This map is actually injective (unlike most restriction maps!) basically because $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is dense. (I think a topological property of the codomain is also being used here, but I don't remember what it is.)

Then because $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is countable, $(\mathbb{R}^n)^{\mathbb{Q}^n}$ has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$. So $\mathfrak{c} \leq |C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)| \leq \mathfrak{c}$ i.e. $|C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n|=\mathfrak{c}$ has the cardinality of the continuum.

Comment: It's also easy to prove that if we have got discrete metric that we've got $2^\mathfrak{c}$ continous functions. But still general case is interesting.

Comment: @BartoszBednarczyk With the discrete metric you have $2^\mathfrak{c}$ open sets, though.